# Command-line cloud file backup?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, command-line

Is there a free cloud file server for personal files
with shell commands like Unix `ls`, `cp` etc. ?
Along the lines

```
cloud ls [-options] pattern
cloud cp-up pattern
cloud cp-down pattern
```

My ideal would be `/Volumes/cloud`; then I could use *all* Unix commands
in scripts, Makefiles ...
(which I'm used to: *waaay* simpler and more comfortable than clicking through GUIs.)

Comment: Are you talking about something like a WebDAV service.?

Comment: Are you looking only for free services or would paid services also do?

Comment: @markhunte, thanks; is there a cloud file server that supports (command-line) WebDAV ?